# Java IOException when reading from a Arduino Analog Stick

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, arduino

Im Trying to create a simple "Game Controller" by connecting a Analog stick to Arduino and processing the sent data in a Java file using Eclipse. Here are the Codes:

Arduino:

```
int Ver = 0;
int Hor = 0;
int data[2];

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Ver = analogRead(A0); //511 D = 0
  Hor = analogRead(A1); //515 L = 0 max = 1023

  data[0] = Ver;
  data[1] = Hor;

  Serial.print("[");
  Serial.print(data[0], DEC);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(data[1], DEC);
  Serial.println("]");
  delay(50);
}
```

Java:

```
package Controller;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class AnalogStick implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM12", // Windows
    };

    private BufferedReader input;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        // First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum
                    .nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Port ID: ");
        System.out.println(portId);
        System.out.println("");
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }


    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }


    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine = input.readLine();
                //System.out.println("" + inputLine);
                String[] items = inputLine.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

                int[] data = new int[items.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        data[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
                }
                //System.out.println("Ver: " + data[0] + " Hor: " + data[1]);

                Robot robot = new Robot();

                    if(data[0] > 511 + 10 && data[1] < 515 + 169 && data[1] > 515 - 169){
                        System.out.println("Up");
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                    }
                    else if(data[0] < 511 - 10 && data[1] < 515 + 169 && data[1] > 515 - 169){
                        System.out.println("Down");
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    }
                    if(data[1] < 515 - 10 && data[0] < 511 + 170 && data[0] > 511 - 170){
                        System.out.println("Left");
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                    }
                    else if(data[1] > 515 + 10 && data[0] < 511 + 170 && data[0] > 511 - 170){
                        System.out.println("Right");
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
                //System.out.println("failed stuff");
            }
        }
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnalogStick main = new AnalogStick();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("- Started -");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I press run on eclipse, and it works fine, but when I shift my mouse pointer to a different screen or try using the analog stick in a game (therefore switching screens), i get the following Error and the analog stick stops functioning within the game:

> java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes

I have a feeling that this error is caused by having too many data sent to the PC before the analog stick is able to process a single input line, but I am not sure since this is the first time I am working with a analog stick. Can somebody teach me 
1) Why its not working as I expect it to work 
2) How to fix this error
and
3) If there is a better way to program a analog stick, tell me how and/or show me a reference website

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem could be stemming from the Arduino code, which is C/C++. Might want to add that to your tags. I am assuming you have started here: http://arduino.cc/en/guide/introduction ?

Comment: Tag added. I used this website as reference: http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-an-Arduino-Uno-R3-as-a-Game-Controller/?ALLSTEPS